# ReflectionException in Container.php line 741: Class 7 does not exist with Laravel5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I would like to provide the functionality to change his/her password on his/her own on my web application but I found the error addressed on the title so can anyone help me to solve this?

url:

```
http://nuatthai.loc/auth/password
```

routing:

```
Route::post('auth/password', ['as' => 'auth.postPassword', 'uses' => 'PasswordController@postPassword']);
Route::get('auth/password', ['as' => 'auth.prePassword', 'uses' => 'PasswordController@prePassword']);
```

Controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use Mail;
use App\Role;
use App\User;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PasswordController extends Controller
{
  use ResourceController;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->middleware('role:' . Role::ADMIN + Role::OWNER + Role::MANAGER + Role::ACCOUNTANT);
  }

  protected function validator(array $data)
  {
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:8',
    ]);
  }

  private function updateData(Request $request)
  {
    $user = User::find($this::getMyId());
    $user->password = $request->input('password');
    $user->remember_token = str_random(60);
    $user->save();

    return $user;
  }

  public function prePassword()
  {
    return view('auth.change');
  }

  public function postPassword($request)
  {
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
      \Session::flash('flash_error', $validator->messages());
      $this->throwValidationException(
        $request, $validator
      );
    }

    $this::updateData($request);
  }
}
```

view:

```
{{-- resources/views/auth/change.blade.php --}}

@extends('common.layout')

@section('header')   @parent @endsection

@section('navbar')   @include('common.navbar') @endsection

@section('sidebar')   @include('common.sidebar') @endsection

@section('content')
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Login</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          @if (count($errors) > 0)
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
              <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
              <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                  <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
              </ul>
            </div>
          @endif

          {!! Form::open(array('action' => ['PasswordController@postPassword'], 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) !!}
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label input-lg">Password</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" name="password">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label input-lg">Confirm Password</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" name="password_confirmation">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="margin-right: 15px;">
                  Reset Password
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div><!-- .panel-body -->
      </div><!-- .panel --> @endsection

{{-- resources/views/auth/change.blade.php --}}
```

middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\Role;
use App\UserRole;
class RoleMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $mode)
    {
      if(!\Auth::check()) {
        // session expired.
        return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
      }
      else {
        $admin = $mode & Role::ADMIN;
        $owner = $mode & Role::OWNER;
        $manager = $mode & Role::MANAGER;
        $accountant = $mode & Role::ACCOUNTANT;

        $type = \Auth::user()->role->type;
        if(($admin) && ($type == Role::ADMIN)) {
          return $next($request);
        }
        if(($owner) && ($type == Role::OWNER)) {
          return $next($request);
        }
        if(($manager) && ($type == Role::MANAGER)) {
          return $next($request);
        }
        if(($accountant) && ($type == Role::ACCOUNTANT)) {
          return $next($request);
        }
        return response('Access Denied.', 403);
      }
    }
}
```

Role:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Http\Controllers\ResourceController;

class Role extends Model
{
  use ResourceController;
  const TABLE = 'common_roles';
  const ROLE_ID = 'role_id';
  const ROLE_TYPE = 'type';
  const TABLE_ROLE_ID = self::TABLE . '.' . self::ROLE_ID;
  const TABLE_ROLE_TYPE = self::TABLE . '.' . self::ROLE_TYPE;

  protected $table = self::TABLE;
  protected $primaryKey = self::ROLE_ID;

  const ADMIN = 0b1000; // 8
  const OWNER = 0b100; // 4
  const MANAGER = 0b10; // 2
  const ACCOUNTANT = 0b1; // 1

  public function users()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
  }
}
```

I really appreciate of any suggestions and advices in advance.

Comment: I missed the error message.

Comment: You need to paste the full log that shows the error.

Comment: I just added the errir. Please refer it.

Comment: show where your "role:" middleware is defined. Is there any way that Role::ADMIN + Role::OWNER + Role::MANAGER + Role::ACCOUNTANT == 7 and that's where the missing classname is coming from?

Comment: I added the code of Role middleware and Role itself.

Comment: As a result, I changed the code of constructor as "$this->middleware('role:' . (Role::ADMIN + Role::OWNER + Role::MANAGER + Role::ACCOUNTANT));" then it worked. lack of "(" and ")".
Thanks, markdwhite.

Comment: Ah! I'm glad something I said pointed you in the right direction :)